# I cannot install GParted on ubuntu gnome 16.04

Tags: boot, gnome, kernel, gparted

Whenever I try to install any packages, I see the following error

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gparted : Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 1:2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libparted-fs-resize0 (>= 3.1) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-52-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-signed-image-4.8.0-52-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic (= 4.8.0-52.55~16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

My /boot device is full. Please give me solution.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get -f install` like the message is saying?

Comment: yes i ran it but still error is same

Comment: Yeah, I just read the other part of your `/boot` being full.  Follow the duplicate link there and remove stuff from your `/boot` folder.  If you keep up and every time there is a new kernel update and run the `sudo apt autoremove` after the update it will remove older kernels no longer needed.

Comment: can you tell me how much size for /boot partition should have ?

Comment: Generally speaking between 100MB - 200MB.  However, it really is not needed unless you are doing LVM or have special BIOS needs, etc.  I really like this answer https://superuser.com/a/160549/440143  I don't use one on my home system because I don't do encrypted drives nor LVM.  It has not given me any grief without having one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to install a package for which there are several unmet dependencies, i.e. other packages on which gparted relies.

You can either try:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Or install EACH dependency manually, for example:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1v5
```

Either way you need to clear some storage if you want to install gparted.

Comment: I tried it but /boot partition is full so i cannot install any dependency and package.Tell me how to increase size of /boot partition.